# Эмуляция ввода текста и эмуляция открития клавиатуры

Tags: android, javascript, клавиатура

В общем, было задание написать игру. Мы решили написать пакмена. Игра должна быть по сети. Пока задумано для неограниченного количества человек. Для реализации игры разработан (разрабатывается) свой движок. Все реализовано таким образом, что на странице находится лишь один единственный элемент canvas. Пару минут назад была поднята тема запуска игры на android-устройствах.

Проблема заключается в следующем:
При запуске игры пользователь должен ввести свое имя (ник), чтобы можно было пользователя опознать и создать канал текущей игры. Андроид не понимает, что нужно открыть клавиатуру для ввода текста. Возможно, некоторые прошивки позволяют открыть клавиатуру в любом месте (моя - нет), но без введенного имени начать игру нельзя.

---

МОЖНО НАЧАТЬ ЧИТАТЬ ОТСЮДА

---

В общем, возможно ли эмулировать открытие клавиатуры на android-устройствах, чтобы при нажатии на элемент canvas открывалась клавиатура?

---

Просто не хочется создавать дополнительные (костыли) input`ы для авторизации.